# How to read the file data from the curl response?

Tags: php, curl

How to read the file content from the curl, Response are in the excel and tsv file content. But try to run from the POSTMAN it's return some output

```
        PKO'Qd��(�M$_rels/.rels BL�굄�BL�굄�BL�굄���Mj1F�b��h�B)%N6��])�T[���X�V���5]��I����
���i4_�r/�²��pp���Zx?
        �,��d��i��N�a�Y��HZ�䮏�F�:����]��J"��i$M��Z��jWu���/�L����/
    �N��͖����}N��
```

But try to run the code from the curl it's showing blank curl code which is using for getting response

```
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$reporturl);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->trade_auth());

        $result = (curl_exec($ch));
```

Please help to read the file using the curl

Comment: whats $this->trade_auth() return and whats curl_error say?

Comment: trade auth passing the header Content-Type and TTD-Auth  no curl error appears

Comment: what are you doing with $result?

Comment: also, check the error log, you might not even have curl installed and there is no error reporting turned on. you need to try and debug abit

Comment: currently want to print the response but after the want to read the file and then put the content in the data base , running 3rd party api which is returning reports details

Comment: curl is working for previous results

Comment: https://api.thetradedesk.com/v3/portal/api/doc/AggregatedReports using this api to get report